# View the most valuable tags (determined by votes per view)

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

We now have a way of determining the most valuable tags! <sup><sub>Okay, okay, so it's all a bit subjective...</sub></sup>

The query '[Most Valuable Questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/478127/605828/most-valuable-questions)' displays the top 500 questions, sorted by `votes/views`, with the option to limit results to questions over a certain amount of votes.

This can be helpful in determining tags that have a high ratio of votes to views, for example, the [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) tag shows up a lot in this list, even for higher-voted questions (much of the list at `votes >= 50` is story-identification, while at `votes >=70` it takes up 3 of the top 4 results, and no others).

Enjoy! and please, post anything interesting you notice as an answer.

http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/478127/613291/most-valuable-questions

> A lot of people have mentioned how the data returned with this query is [not representative of the majority of questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9518/view-the-most-valuable-tags-determined-by-votes-per-view#comment25791_9519) on the site, as the trend is skewed by low view-counts.
>
> With this in mind, I edited the query to limit the results by view count, instead of vote count.
>
> Here it is: [Most Valuable Questions (Limited By Views)](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/478127/613291/most-valuable-questions)

Comment: You might like to post this as an answer to [What are some useful Stack Exchange Data Explorer queries for this site?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/what-are-some-useful-stack-exchange-data-explorer-queries-for-this-site)

Comment: Can you sum all the scores by tag?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage you mean `total votes in tag/total views of tag`? It could be possible, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: That's what I was thinking,  but maybe the average is a better measure.

Answer (score 4):

### At `votes >= 0`

- [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) comprises 44.8% of all valuable questions, or 224 of 500
- [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) comprises 3.8%, or 19 of 500
- [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) comprises 3%, or 15 of 500
- [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) comprises 1.6%, or 8 of 500

### At `votes >= 20`

- [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) comprises 21.6%, or 108 of 500
- [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) comprises 15% of all valuable questions, or 75 of 500
- [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) comprises 12%, or 60 of 500
- [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) comprises 9.8%, or 49 of 500
- [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) comprises 1.2%, or 6 of 500

### At `votes >= 100`

- [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) comprises ~35.56%, or 16 of 45
- [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) comprises ~15.56%, or 7 of 45
- [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) comprises ~11.11%, or 5 of 45
- [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) comprises ~2.22% of all valuable questions, or 1 of 45
- [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) comprises ~2.22%, or 1 of 45

---

## Conclusions

- Story identification figures strongly in the lower-voted questions
- Star Trek and Star Wars become more valuable among higher-voted questions

Comment: What order are those tags in?

Comment: @ibid no order, they're just tags that I happened to notice (so yeah, it's not the most objective way of drawing conclusions...)

Comment: Shouldn't they be put in order of most valuable to least valuable?

Comment: @ibid sure, but I really need to go through the data again and actually select the top tags, then write it up. You'll notice there's not even [tag:lord-of-the-rings] in there...

Comment: I modified the query slightly to get the total views for the questions in the results and all the questions. When setting the min score to 0, the result is 47879 views out of 75925514 total views. This is about 0.063% of all views. I'm not sure that's a representative sample. The maximum score in that category is only 21, and the maximum number of views is only 328 (very small in StackExchange terms).  A question with 16 views and a score of 1 even makes it into that set! That hardly seems like one of the "most useful questions". The small number of views dominates more than anything.

Comment: @jpmc26 good point. I did make a query where one could specify the number of views instead of votes, but decided against it because views aren't noticed as much as votes are. Maybe you could slightly modify mine to use views, to make it more valid? also, do you have a link to your query?

Comment: I didn't save them, but all I did was make your query a subquery and put a `SUM` on the view count. (I removed the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` for the total.)